# Azure Application Gateway redirect rule limit

Tags: azure

I am planning to migrate new and old sites using Azure Application Gateway.

For migration, I need to migrate from the old site to the new site page by page.

I'm thinking of using Azure Application Gateway's URL redirect, but is there an upper limit on the number of redirect rule definitions?

There are tens of thousands of pages to be migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The published limit is 100 redirect rules per application gateway according to the documentation.  Reference:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#application-gateway-limits

Do you really need to do the mapping and redirect at the page level?  Is it possible to migrate a directory or folder at a time?

Comment: Hi Mike.

THX for your reply.

I understand limitation of redirect rules.